# jQuery get content of all the span's before and after the selected

Tags: jquery

I wrote this code : 
HTML

```
<p>
    Once upon a time there was a man
    who lived in a pizza parlor. This
    man just loved pizza and ate it all
    the time.  He went on to be the
    happiest man in the world.  The end.
</p>
```

JS:

```
var words = $("p:first").text().split(" ");
var text = words.join("</span> <span>");
$("p:first").html("<span>" + text + "</span>");
$("span").click(function() {
    $(this).html('<input value="'+$(this).text() +'"/>');
    $(this).unbind("click");
});
```

Now i want when the user clicks on the word a input box opens up and i want when the users `blurs` from the input box it should change the word in the `p` accordingly.

**QUESTION**

How can i get all the text before and after the text of where the input box is shown ?
And then reset the value of `p` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changed it to :

```
var words = $("p:first").text().split(" ");
var text = words.join("</span> <span>");
$("p:first").html("<span>" + text + "</span>");
$("span").click(function() {
    $(this).html('<input class="mm" value="' + $(this).text() + '"/>');
    $(this).unbind("click");
});
$("#hmm").delegate(".mm", "blur", function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<span>"+$(this).val()+"</span>");
    $(this).bind("click");
});
```

And it works like charm

Answer (score 0):

I had some weird behaviour with the 'blur' event so I adapted your brief a little, try this - it will hopefully still give you the effect you want -

```
var words = $("p:first").text().split(" ");
var text = words.join("</span> <span>");
$("p:first").html("<span>" + text + "</span>");
$("span").click(function() {
    $("span input[class=tb]").each(function(
           {$(this).parent('span').html($(this).val())
    });
    $(this).html('<input class="tb" value="'+$(this).text() +'"/>');
    $(this).unbind("click");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/Sx85y/

Comment: The blur event didn't always seem to fire for me - so I only remove the textbox after another word is clicked. Pleased you got it working.